# Using Reflections to create new class instances

Tags: java, reflection

I am experimenting with reflections library found at:https://code.google.com/p/reflections/

What I am trying to achieve, is scan a package within my project, and then create instances of all the subclasses of a given type, found within that package. 
The way I am using the library is correct, as subTypes returns the following:

> [class identifiers.DNSLookup, class identifiers.AliasChecker, class
>   identifiers.GoogleSafeBrowsing]

Although my problem is how I can create new instances of the classes found within that set. All of them have no-argument constructors.

```
private void getDetectors(){
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("identifiers"); //name of package to scan

        Set<Class<? extends DetectorSub>> subTypes =
                reflections.getSubTypesOf(DetectorSub.class);
        System.out.println(subTypes); // correct classes included here.
        for(Class<? extends DetectorSub> detector:subTypes){
            try {
                DetectorSub d =(DetectorSub)detector.getClass().newInstance().cast(DetectorSub.class); //returns exceptions at runtime.
            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code returns the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Can not call newInstance() on the Class for java.lang.Class
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:339)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    at core.PhishingScanner.getDetectors(PhishingScanner.java:40)
    at core.PhishingScanner.<init>(PhishingScanner.java:28)
    at core.Main.main(Main.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

As a final note, Is it possible to use the above functionality to scan classes based on their interface, rather than superclass? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code:

```
for(Class<? extends DetectorSub> detector:subTypes){
```

Here `detector` is an instance of `Class<? extends DetectorSub>`

And then:

```
DetectorSub d =(DetectorSub)detector.getClass().newInstance().cast(DetectorSub.class);
```

You are calling `getClass()` on `detector`, that is you're calling getClass() on a `Class<? extends DetectorSub>` instance and you obtain the class object that represents `Class` and not the subType of `DetectorSub` anymore. So when you create a new instance, you are actually trying to create a new instance of `Class`, which fails, since the default constructor of `Class` is private.

You should write instead:

```
DetectorSub d = detector.newInstance();
```

Comment: Uff same answer in same minute :(

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean?

```
DetectorSub d = (DetectorSub) detector.getDeclaredConstructors()[0].newInstance();

// or DetectorSub d = (DetectorSub) detector.newInstance();
// since it invokes the no-args constructor
```

Comment: detector.newInstance is working im wondering how I missed that method when scrolling through available ones. The one you posted returns :
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class core.PhishingScanner can not access a member of class java.lang.Class with modifiers "private"

Answer (score 0):

On line

```
DetectorSub d =(DetectorSub)detector.getClass().newInstance().cast(DetectorSub.class);
```

there is no need to call `getClass()` again. It should be just:

```
DetectorSub d =(DetectorSub)detector.newInstance().cast(DetectorSub.class);
```